# Can we disable binary logging for one specific session or user in AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, replication, amazon-rds, aws

Currently we have a situation to disable binary logging for one set of queries on AWS RDS. We thought to set log-bin=0 for that specific session. As per Amazon, this is not possible. Is there any work around for us ?

1. We want binary logging to be working for the remaining activity that happens in parallel 
   to this session.
2. If needed, we can stop and restart slave.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

One solution proposed in https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=45258 requires setting backup retention period to zero. Which should mean no automatic backup! But you can still take manual snapshots.

Answer (score -3):

I apologise if I misunderstood (I don't use Amazon RDS). But can you use:

```
SET SESSION SQL_LOG_BIN = 0;

-- DO STUFF HERE

SET SESSION SQL_LOG_BIN = 1;
```

After setting it to 0, it will prevent everything in your current session being written to the Binary logs. Setting it back to 1 will resume writing to be binary logs. Everything else continues as per normal.

Comment: IGGt, thanks for ur inputs. As per AWS MYSQL RDS, they said they cant disable session level bin logging as it required SUPER privilege.  NOTE: AWS RDS doesnt support SUPER privilege.